# how to search date using datepicker in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date

how to search date in mysql? i am using datetimepicker in vb.net to search a specific data on database. but it seems that my search query is not accurate. there is wrong or something on my code.

here is my code in vb.net

```
Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT * FROM complaint WHERE date BETWEEN '" & DATE.Text & "' AND '" & DATE2.Text & "'"
```

here is my screenshot to understand more my problem:

[image: scrnsht1]

**i search date from 12/11/2013 to 12/11/2013 and based on my screenshot no. 1 it has result**

[image: scr2]

**When i change the value of datetimepicker to 12/2/2013 to 12/11/2013 no results was retrieved.**

does anyone know what's the problem on this? pls help and share to me on how to fix this guys. thank you so much!!

Comment: you should use a command.

Comment: i already used a command sir. the code works but its not accurate enough. pls see my screenshot sir

Comment: pass your dates as a parameter instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Have you tried to run the query in database side? by entering actual dates??

Comment: yes sir. i have. but when i change the datepicker from 12/2/2013 to 12/11/2013 no results was retrieved. to understand more there is screenshot above sir

Comment: yes i got that ... just try to run the query in database side

Comment: run query in db side change dateformat in front end

Comment: how do you mean in changing the dateformat in front end sir?

Comment: i run the mysql query in database side and no results found

Comment: so there's date issue from database side.... might be format of date..

Comment: ahh. the database side should be formatted to date? okay sir i'll try that

Comment: exactly and from front end also convert to date type...

Comment: yess! it worked sir rony! thank you so much!!!

Comment: @SheerwoodJohnCaday- please mark my answer as your correct answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT * FROM complaint WHERE date >= @startdate AND date <= @enddate"
```

if your date format from mysql is "yyyy-MM-dd", then you have to change the value in datetimepicker to exactly the same "yyyy-MM-dd"

```
cmd.Parameters.Addwithvalue("@startdate", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))

cmd.Parameters.Addwithvalue("@enddate", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

*Note:* cmd is your MySqlCommand